# PHP DateTime exception and errors handling

Tags: php, datetime

How can I prevent PHP to crash when creating a DateTime object?

```
$in = new DateTime($in);
$out = new DateTime($out);
```

`$in` and `$out` both comes from a form so they could be anything. I enforce the user to use a calendar and block it to dates with javascript. What if the user can bypass this check?

If `$in = "anything else other than a date"` PHP will crash and block the rendering of the whole page.

How do I prevent this and just `return(0)` if PHP is not able to parse the date?

Comment: Read the documentation (the "Errors/Exceptions" part). http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.construct.php#refsect1-datetime.construct-errors

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Check out the documentation on `DateTime()`, here's a little snippet:

```
<?php
try {
    $date = new DateTime('2000-01-01');
} catch (Exception $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage();
    exit(1);
}

echo $date->format('Y-m-d');
?>
```

[PHP Manual DateTime::__construct()](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.construct.php)

Comment: This exception won't be catch, as a fatal error is thrown. See this comment on same documentation page: https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.construct.php#113342

Comment: This is great but any ideas how to catch *only* Invalid datetime format exception, instead of a generic exception?

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, but I'm still mystified as to _why_ php would be written this way. What on earth is the point of making this uncatchable? It seems perverse.

Answer (score 8):

[`strtotime()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php) will return false if the format is bad so this *should* catch bad formats.

```
if (strtotime($in) === false)
{
     // bad format
}
```

Comment: This doesn't work for values like "30.11.-1" (which is 0000-00-00), the var_dump is then int(-62169987600).

Answer (score 4):

What about exception handling?

```
try {
    $in = new DateTime($in);
} catch (Exception $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage();
    return(0);
}
```

Comment: Interestingly the class factory DateTime::createFromFormat does *not* throw an exception when it cannot interpret the string, but instead returns false. It thereby breaks the OOP model

Answer (score 3):

The `DateTime` [constructor](http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.construct.php) will throw an Exception if the date/time string cannot be parsed. You can catch it. Have a look at the following snippet:

```
try   {
    $dt = new DateTime('10th - 12th June 2013'); // bad date string
} catch (Exception $e) {
    var_dump($e->getMessage());
}
```