# echo new DateTime(); on wordpress causes critical error

Tags: php, datetime

If I go on my wordpress site

```
<?php $theCurrentDate = new DateTime(); ?>
<?php echo $theCurrentDate; ?>
```

It causes a critical error on my website, why?

[PHP DateTime exception and errors handling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16019126/php-datetime-exception-and-errors-handling)

```
<?php 
  try   {
     $dt = new DateTime();
     echo $dt;
  } catch (Exception $e) {
     var_dump($e->getMessage());
  }
?>
```

I still get critical error on site.

What is going on here? Howcome when you echo datetime() in php it breaks wordpress?

Comment: What's the error?

Comment: I figured it out apparently you have to specify format or it just crashes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.format.php

Apparently you have to specify format

```
<?php $theCurrentDate = new DateTime(); ?>
<?php echo $theCurrentDate->format('Y-m-d H:i:s'); ?>
```